# CSS border-bottom line not directly under text

Tags: css, html

I just started learning HTML5 in congruence with CSS, and I am trying to make my own resume (exercise from Codecademy). My issue is with the subheading divs I am planning to make, where I am trying to place a black line underneath the subheading text. There is large gap in between the line and text, however.

```css
#header {
  margin-top: -3.5px;
  background-color: #C3CDD4;
  height: 90px;
  width: 98.5%;
  position: relative;
}

#name {
  font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  /*padding bottom: 50px;*/
}

#address {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  float:right;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

#contact {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  float: right;
  clear: left;
  margin-top:-60px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.subheader {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: -2.5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <p id="name"> Vincent William Barker </p>
      <p id="address">67294 Washington Way</p>
      <p id="contact">999.999.9999 · vwbarker@gmail.com</p>

    </div>

    <div class="subheader">
      <h4 class="subheader_title">Education</h4>

    </div>


    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what the site currently looks like? Please also point out the gap you are talking about.

Comment: It is exactly what it looks like if you run the code snippet. I want the black line to be directly underneath 'Education'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want the sides of your `div` to be straight, remove the property `border-radius: 5px;`. The space between your line and the subheader was due to this property - `height: 100px;` in your `.subheader` div. Remove that property and your problem will be fixed. To make it closer to the subheader, you will have to delete its border bottom property. After that, make a new div and look at its properties below.

```css
#header {
  margin-top: -3.5px;
  background-color: #C3CDD4;
  height: 90px;
  width: 98.5%;
  position: relative;
}
#name {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  /*padding bottom: 50px;*/
}
#address {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: 60px;
}
#contact {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  float: right;
  clear: left;
  margin-top: -60px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.subheader {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: -2.5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
.line {
  margin-top: -20px;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <p id="name">Vincent William Barker</p>
    <p id="address">67294 Washington Way</p>
    <p id="contact">999.999.9999 · vwbarker@gmail.com</p>

  </div>

  <div class="subheader">
    <h4 class="subheader_title">Education</h4>

  </div>
  <div class="line">

    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What properties would I used to play with the spacing? I want to move it even closer underneath the text. Line-height and padding-bottom don't seem to work out

Comment: I will answer that too.

Comment: thanks man! I am not sure why you were downvoted, but you have thoroughly answered my question.